# Tools for cnf management, generation?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Does anyone know of any good tools for cnf configuration management?  It's often the case I have a group of machines that has a very similar config except for a few differences such as server id or buffer pools to match their specific hardware.

I'm looking for something where I can setup a general template, tell it I want to generate some configs for that machine from that template, have it prompt me for the variables that need to be filled in and write out the .cnfs for me.

Answer (score 5):

Percona just built a tool to do just that called the [Configuration Wizard](http://tools.percona.com/members/wizard). I tested it out once just to see what it would return and the results were pretty darn close to what we were using on our servers, whose cnf's were put together by highly trained mysql certified dba's.

Comment: That's a neat toy but not what I was looking for.  I was thinking something more along the lines of a puppet or chef management system.  One of those may actually work out for what I'm wanting but I haven't played with them enough to know for sure.